# How can I edit a Presentation in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive

Google Drive shows me presentations, spreadsheets and documents, but I only can edit spreadsheets and documents.

So I'd like to edit the presentation locally, but I can't find a way to download it in the first place.

For edit in a tablet, for example with Polaris Office or other free apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of [June 25, 2014](https://drive.googleblog.com/2014/06/newdocssheetsslides.html), Google published [Google Slides](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.docs.editors.slides) - its collaborative presentation platform - for Android. After installing the app, when you select a presentation from the Google Drives app, it will open the file in Google Slides and let you edit it.

It also supports offline editing. You have to sync the content of your Drives first, but after that, you can edit it offline in Google Slides. The file will be synced to Drives when the internet connection is available.

[image: Google Slides]

<sub>Image taken from its Play Store page.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the mobile app offers this feature but at least via the web interface you can export your documents to OpenDocument files which you can edit locally. Afterwards, you can upload the edited version.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Android 4.4 so this is how I do it.

When in google drive...

1. click on the (i) on the file you want to download.
2. It opens a menu (seen in the screenshot below).
3. On that menu, click the vertical ... in the top right to open the menu.
4. Click on "Download a copy"

The file is now in your downloads folder.
You can now edit it offline using your favorite office suite. (I recommend Kingston Office.)
Find it using a File manager Like [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fm.clean&referrer=52DD70F0D50DF)

[image: Access]